# I need to generate a customized report every week by exporting data from JIRA to excel. Is there a way to create macros for this?

Tags: excel, macros, jira

I run reports in JIRA and then export them to excel. I then work on this data to create control charts in excel. How can i use macros (or any other tool) that would help me run this process of exporting the report and then customizing to create control charts every once a week?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite general, so there are many possible solutions:

- Use a commercial reporting add-on like [EazyBI](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.eazybi.jira.plugins.eazybi-jira/server/overview) or [Arsenale Dataplane](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.arsenalesystems.dataplane/server/overview)
- Use the [JIRA REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/) to script your own solution. There are different possibilities here as well:

  - Retrieve the info you need using the [search REST resource](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/search-search), then generate your own output file in csv or another excel compatible format.
  - Use VBA from within Excel to retrieve all the info you need.
- Some more options in [this post on Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/546/how-can-i-scheduleautomate-excel-reports-in-jira)